# check hover on mouseleave of element

Tags: jquery

I've something like below code:

html:

```
<a href="#">foo</a>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    console.log('hovered');
},function(){
    if($('#bar').is(':hover')===false){
        console.log('bar is not hovered');
    }
});
```

But here on mouseleave of `foo` I wanted to check if the `bar` is hovered or not. So from `foo` mouse moves to `bar` but it logs me bar is not hovered.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57eynm9h/)

Comment: It works for me, Chrome latest version.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be caused by the order that Internet Explorer processes the CSS and Javascript. There is no gap between the elements, so that is not the problem. Your code works properly in Chrome.

This is a bit ugly, but it supports my conclusion that Internet Explorer is processing the Javascript before the CSS changes & it does provide a way to get the results you would expect. Adding a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` solves your problem by pausing the Javascript long enough for the CSS to be processed.

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    console.log('hovered');
},function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($('#bar').is(':hover')===false){
            console.log('bar is not hovered');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frecks/nvg1etdy/).

You may also want to read through this question ([Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)), as it has some really useful info explaining what is going on.

Comment: combining both of answer (your and husen) resulted fine work for me so, I'm unsure to accept an answer... so +1 for both answer...

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/57eynm9h/10/)

function nesting will work as per your requirements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hover(function(){
        console.log('A link is hovered');
    },function(){
        console.log('A link is Not hovered');
        $('#bar').hover(function(){
            console.log('Div is hovered');          
        },function(){
            console.log('Div is Not hovered');
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Be sure that there is no **gap** between your elements. Check this CSS for example:

```
#bar{
    float: left;
    background: green;
}

a {
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
```

The `float` will not generate any gap between elements. Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57eynm9h/2/).